# Using Mitov.Plotlab in my C# project, "Entry not found" error messagebox raise in design

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, plotlab

[error window one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpQLZ.png)

ps: The translation for image: "无法找到入口" -> "Entry not found", "无法定位程序输入点 于动态链接库" -> "Can not locate the program entry point in the dynamic link library."

In other compute is ok, this quiestion only in my notebook.

- OS: win10 enterprise
- VS Version: 2015
- Plotlab Version: 7.8.2
- Error Window Number: many of them

I tried many way:

1. List item
2. update system
3. Repair vs2015
4. Install all version with C++
5. Running with administrator
6. Install on C:\
7. Reinstall Plotlab

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Boian Mitov.

You probably have switched from an older installation, and there is some left over stuff.

Can you please try this version first:
http://www.mitov.com/PlotLab_NET_7.8.2.95.zip

There are some improvements in it.

Comment: And I solve the question after reinstall OS with win10 professional .beacuse i used win10 home,  update OS to win10 professional not solve it.